# Haskell filter option concatenation

Tags: parsing, haskell, filter, concatenation

```
exchangeSymbols "a§ b$ c. 1. 2. 3/" = filter (Char.isAlphaNum) (replaceStr str " " "_")
```

The code above is supposed to first replace all "spaces" with "`_`", then filter the String according to `Char.isAlphaNum`. Unfortunately the `Char.isAlphaNum` part absorbs the already exchanged "_", which isn't my intention and i want to hold the "`_`". So, i thought it would be nice just add an exception to the filter which goes like:

```
exchangeSymbols "a§ b$ c. 1. 2. 3/" = filter (Char.isAlphaNum && /='_') (replaceStr str " " "_")
```

You see the added `&& not /='_'`. It produces a `parse error`, obviously it is not so easily possible to concatenate filter options, but is there a smart workaround ? I thought about wrapping the filter function, like a 1000 times or so with each recursion adding a new filter test `(/='!')`,`(/='§')` and so on without adding the `(/='_')`. However it doesn't seem to be a handy solution.

Comment: please read the whole post then answer delnan.

Comment: Nevermind, I read "added" and my tired brain though there was a second one =/ Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing

`... filter (Char.isAlphaNum && /='_') ...`

is actually a type error (the reason why it yields a parse error is maybe that you used /= as prefix - but its an infix operator). You cannot combine **functions** with `(&&)` since its an operator on booleans (not on functions).

Acutally this code snipped should read:

`... filter (\c -> Char.isAlphaNum c && c /= '_') ...`

Comment: Hey, it looks like you began using `c` then switched to `x`, so I went ahead and fixed that for you. :)

Comment: Same as above, the Char.isAlphaNum is pre-dominant, again not the output i want. I'll try it the long way and define a `filterAllSignsEXCEPT_SPACE_CHAR` by concatenating mutlitple filter funcs.

Comment: Change the `&&` to `||`, and `/=` to `==` and it should work, as you want those that are _either_ alphanumeric _or_ an underscore.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your filter with a list comprehension.

`[x | x <- replaceStr str " " "_", x /= '_', Char.isAplhaNum x]`

Naturally, you probably want to have multiple exceptions. So define a helper function:

```
notIn :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Bool
notIn [] _ = True
notIn x:xs y = if x == y
                  then False
                  else notIn xs
```

EDIT: Apparently you can use `notElem :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool` instead. Leaving above code for educational purposes.

And use that in your list comprehension:

`[x | x <- replaceStr str " " "_", notElem x "chars to reject", Char.isAlphaNum x]`

Untested, as haskell isn't installed on this machine. Bonus points if you are doing a map after the filter, since you can then put that in the list comprehension.

Edit 2: Try this instead, I followed in your footsteps instead of thinking it out myself:

```
[x | x <- replaceStr str " " "_", Char.isAlphaNum x || x == ' ']
[x | x <- replaceStr str " " "_", Char.isAlphaNum x || x `elem` "chars to accept"]
```

At this point the list comprehension doesn't help much. The only reason I did change it was because I you requested an `&&`, for which using a list comprehension is great.

Since it seems that you don't quite understand the principle of the list comprehension, its basically applying a bunch of filters and then a map with more than one source, for example:

`[(x, y, x + y) | x <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y <- [2, 4], x > y]`

Comment: Your `notIn` is defined in the Prelude as `notElem`. (Although with the arguments in the opposite order).

Comment: @hammar thanks! I suspected it might be. Should have hoogled that; I knew about elem but didn't really think about it at the time.

Comment: Where exactly should `notIn` or `notElem` be placed ?

Comment: My_test_string is `"a b c 1 2 3 !$%"` should be made to `"a_b_c"_1_2_3_`, but again output is just "abc". Seems Char.isAlphaNum dominates everything, it may be due to the missing Type Definition. I need some strong type definition like `exchangeSymbols :: (replaceStr function return Types) -> (Char.isAlphaNum-Types) -> [output-List-type] `. I'll try phynfo's solution next, this list comprehension stuff above seems kind of fussy. However, thanks to mathepic anyways.